# /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, package-management, java

I have follow all the post but unable to solve this problem:

By mistake I deleted the  `/usr/bin/java`. After installing many time m still getting this error.

After running `update-alternatives --display java` I'm getting:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

Comment: Please clarify. When do you get this error? How have you tried to fix it exactly?

Comment: @Zanna when i do java or java -version i get this error i have follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/634024/bash-usr-bin-java-no-such-file-or-directory     but still same problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `update-alternatives --display java`

Comment: @steeldriver I have  updeted my question

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /usr/bin/java` says? If it shows the package name, try `sudo apt-get purge <package>`, then install it again.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Almost. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <PACKAGE>` would be better.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I just didn't find in https://packages.ubuntu.com/ a package providing `/usr/bin/java`, so I assumed it's something dowloaded e.g. from Oracle's site. In this case I don't think `--reinstall` would help *(unless dpkg cached the package?)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel  dpkg -S /usr/bin/java shows  "no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/java

Comment: How did you install Java in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, run the following:

```
update-java-alternatives -l | awk '{ print $1; }'
```

Pick one of the listed options, and run:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s the-option-you-chose
```

Comment: after running update-java-alternatives -l | awk '{ print $1; }'  output what i get is  java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64   and then i run  sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  i get update-java-alternatives: directory does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: In that case, it's likely that OpenJDK itself was removed. To reinstall, assuming you're using Ubuntu 14.04, use either `sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-7-jre` or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-7-jdk`.